# How to make pandas.cut always start with the lowest bin?

Tags: pandas, cut, bins

could you please let me know how to achieve the following:

I have a dataframe, in which I would like to bin column "cum_vol":

```
 Time       abs_quant        cum_vol       
 17:40:00   294710.0         294710.0         
 17:35:00   10626240.3       10920950.3       
 17:30:00   248827899.4      259748849.7
```

For bin intervals I have a series: [0, 10000, 32000, 42000, 11000000]
If I bin df['cum_vol'] into those bins, I receive the lowest bin of 2 (which makes sense, because the very first value in cum_vol exceeds the first bin).

How can I modify pandas.cut, so that binning ALWAYS starts with the first bin? So, for the df I would like to have a new column "bins" that contains 1, 4, etc. for the corresponding values of cum_vol?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Using spaces as the thousands separator is extremely confusing. Also, what do you mean by "the lowest bin of 2"? The second bin, The counts within a bin?

Comment: Separators have been removed. "The lowest bin of 2" means that pd.cut allocates the very first value into bin 2, not to bin 1